# Google search showing the wrong thumbnail image

Tags: thumbnails, meta-tags, meta

I know that according to Google [this](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1626955?hl=en) is all we need to do to display a certain thumbnail in the Google search results. What could be the case for my thumbnail not to show and Google insisting on showing a random thumbnail from my website?

I have the PageMap and the metatag, is it a problem to use both?

It's a Wordpress site, I have placed the PageMap and metatag on the header.php file.

I have requested a new indexation from Google which resulted in yet again a wrong image showing...

Comment: As your title says Google Search, but the link goes to Google Custom Search: which one do you mean?

Comment: ...What? Google search results. I'm sorry but it is obvious what I want to achieve I don't understand your question.

Comment: As I said, your link goes to documentation about Google Custom Search (which is a different service than Google Search). -- What kind of pages do you want a thumbnail for? As far as I know, Google Search only displays them for a few special types of pages; most results don’t get one.

Comment: Our page is showing a thumbnail in the Google search results in mobile. But it's just a random image from our website. I managed to block that but I'd like to show our logo.

Comment: @Sergi did you ever figure this out? I've tried a few different things with no luck.